# Unable to pass service account in gcloud run deploy command. Getting regex validation error for the passed service account

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gcloud, service-accounts

In Sandbox environment I can see the service account for the deployed container and we can access all the data. but while deploying the container in dev environment I can't see the service account in GKE project. Please check the below image for reference. So, I am trying to pass the service account in gcloud run command with below command, but getting regex error.

[image]

```bash
gcloud run deploy $service_name \
--no-cpu-throttling \
--image=$image_name \
--project=$GKE_PROJECT \
--platform=gke \
--cluster=$CLUSTER \
--cluster-location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION \
--impersonate-service-account=$IMP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
--service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
--namespace=$test
```

> `Error: (gcloud.run.deploy) HTTPError 400: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"admission webhook "validation.webhook.serving.knative.dev" denied the request: validation failed: invalid value: $PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com: spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName\na lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?(\.a-z0-9?)*')","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}`

I can see this service account has editor and service account user roles. tried with different service accounts but still getting same erorr.

[image]

Comment: Please share the document you are referring to to implement this.

Comment: It appears (!?) that you're not correctly substituting the value for `SERVICE_ACOUNT`. The error shows that the value (!) it's receiving is `$PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` which isn't a valid (Service Account) email address. The `PROJECT_ID` is not being substituted. This is the incorrect value too. The value should not be the Project ID. It should be the Project Number (!). So, two problems.

Comment: @DazWilkin Due to security issues i didn't provide my project-id here. There i am giving valid id which is already being used.

Comment: Dunno. I wonder if the error is something of a red-herring. When you `cloud run deploy` to GKE, can the service use a Google Cloud Service Account? Or must it use a Kubernetes Service Account?

Comment: The regex in the error is also (presented) incorrectly. It's definitely not `a-z0-9?(\.a-z0-9?)*`

Comment: We are checking that whether we must use KSA and any account that is binding with GCP account.' a-z0-9' we are passing valid project-id only with numeric values.

Comment: You may try to run the command by removing the `--service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \ `, and check if it works without this, as the error may occur if the service account is not being passed correctly as also mentioned by @DazWilkin.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar we can deploy our images without that, but here our requirement to pass service account at the time of deployment as we are addressing some permission issues to the required buckets. here this error is related to Kub service account. We need to create one Kub service account and bind it with gcp account. Then we can go a head with this. We are working on it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `gcloud run deploy` is used to deploy a container to Cloud Run.
While you deploy container images to Google Cloud Run and when you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is automatically assigned the default service account in the same namespace.
As the error describes, there seems to be an issue with the naming annotation.The name of a ServiceAccount object must be a valid DNS subdomain name.
As the error also mentions the name should be valid for the RFC 1123 label, check for the naming rules,which includes as below.

RFC 1123 Label Names
Some resource types require their names to follow the DNS label standard as defined in RFC 1123.
This means the name must:

- contain at most 63 characters
- contain only lowercase alphanumeric characters or '-' start with an
  alphanumeric character
- end with an alphanumeric character

You may want to verify these standards and check again to see if this works.

Also please note that the Service account is associated with the revision of the service. The service account represents the identity of the running revision, and determines what permissions the revision has. For the managed platform, this is the email address of an IAM service account. For the Kubernetes-based platforms (gke, kubernetes), this is the name of a Kubernetes service account in the same namespace as the service. If not provided, the revision will use the default service account of the project, or default Kubernetes namespace service account respectively.